# Is it possible to call one extension from another

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have Google Chrome and the extensions installed on it. I would like to reduce number of extension buttons on Chrome panel.

For this I want to create my plugin which will display popup window and allow to run another extension installed on my browser?

Is it possible and where I can find examples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to execute another chrome extension using your own chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902913/is-it-possible-to-execute-another-chrome-extension-using-your-own-chrome-extensi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The messaging API has an [external extension feature](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html#external). You can use that communicate between extensions.