# Is it possible to execute another chrome extension using your own chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Essentially I want to be able to program my own extension to trigger another extension for certain purposes. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to manage other extensions, you could take a look at [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management), for your case, I believe you'd like to check [management.setEnabled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#method-setEnabled), it allows you to enable/disable another extension.

If you mean to communicate with an running extension for message passing and you have control on both of the two extensions, you could use [Cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external) to communicate with other extensions.

Comment: Please note that "enable" is not the same as "invoke", which is what I think is being asked. Unless an extension cooperates (that is, is open for messaging), the most you can do is to create a tab with `chrome-extension://otherextensionid/page.html` which may have side effects. You can't trigger a click on an action button, for instance.